# Disable automatic update of Email Opt Out SF field while using LogUnsubEvent Execute Call in MC

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, marketing-cloud-connect, cloudpage, marketingcloudapi

We are using the [LogUnsubEvent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/unsubscribing_and_logging_an_unsubevent_with_a_logunsubevent_execute_call.html) execute SOAP API call in order to opt-out subscribers from emails in MC. We notice this call automatically updates in SF the Email Opt Out standard field to TRUE once unsubscription is successful (this applies to both leads and contacts).

Is there any way to disable this field update in SF? Perhaps a parameter that should be set as part of the call?

Thanks for the helpers,
Barak

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you observe comes with Marketing Cloud Connect, which is a managed package, meaning you cannot alter its behavior.

What MC Connect does is not controllable in the SOAP call either, at least I haven't found that documented anywhere. I would be greatly surprised if such an integral function would have been rewritten for an optional feature, and then it was forgotten to add that to either the function's or MC connect's documentation.
So you likely won't find a way to stop this from happening ex ante, unless you want to uninstall Marketing Cloud Connect.

Inside Sales Cloud, you can of course reset the field back to false after it was set to true, or use AMPscript updateSingleSalesforceObject function from SFMC to perform that action from a connected SFMC org. Both approaches however can only start ex post, so *after* logUnsubEvent has set the field to true.
Doing it in SFSC would be my preferred approach, as that is "agnostic", in that it also catches list-unsubscriptions, not just those LogUnsubEvents that you write yourself and possibly embed in some AMPScript.

Comment: Thanks Jonas for the detailed explanation. However, resetting the email opt out field back to its original value (=False) is not an option for us as we have a process in SFSC that is triggered immediately whenever email opt out = True. Perhaps there is some kind of workaround to prevent this field update in the first place? Thanks

Comment: Hi, understand the situation. Academic interest aside, I think this isn't worth pursuing. Even if you find a way to control _your_ LogUnsubEvent implementation (by changing the SOAP call in some undocumented way), other paths like list-unsubscription (my rule of thumb here, mileage may vary: 10% of unsubs) will be outside of your control as they completely bypass that SOAP call. So they will keep changing the field to true, in case MC Connect is installed. So what I'm saying is - even if you solve this, your solution will have holes. You might have less work overall changing your sfsc process.